# LSB: Raise network interface hang

Tags: debian, systemd, vmware

When starting a Debian Jessie iso in VMWare, I sometimes find the VM won't startup reporting:

```
A start job is running for LSB: Raise network interface
```

A timer then loops forever counting seconds from 1-60s. What can I do about this? How can I debug what is happening?

I'm using the stock `debian-8.1.0-amd64-netinst.iso` file.

During the Debian installer, network autoconfiguration works just fine. The `netinst` minimal install requires a bunch of stuff downloaded from the tubes - which successfully completes.

This problem only arises on the first boot of the OS.

Comment: Not enough information. How is the network interface configured? That's an installation ISO, not an independently functioning system.

Comment: I totally agree that's not enough information. How do I get more? Typically these VMs just start without problem, but recently that's not been the case.

Comment: https://github.com/boxcutter/debian/blob/master/debian81.json

Comment: That's the packer config used to start the VM

Comment: Maybe it's waiting for a DHCP offer? Is your DHCP server functional and reachable from the VM? Check with `tcpdump`.

Comment: DHCP is up on the network. You check this with the vmnet-cli command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by destroying the VMWare networking configuration and recreating it. Thanks @Ferenc Wágner for pointing me in the right direction ;)

```
# stop VMWare networking and recreate base config
sudo ~/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --stop
sudo rm -rf /Library/Preferences/VMware\ Fusion/networking* 
sudo rm -rf /Library/Preferences/VMware\ Fusion/vmnet*
sudo ~/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --configure
```

You will need to restart VMWare if it is running. (I found the command line `vmnet-cli --start` command did not work - only starting the OSX app fixed networking).

Comment: This didn't solve the problem for me. :(